# dimm display when pressing energy save button

Tags: windows-7, power-consumption

In Windows 7 how can I automatically dimm the display when I press the energy save button of my laptop. I do not find a setting for this  to this explicitly when pressing the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What model of laptop? There is always a utility or driver for the laptop keyboard to make the specials keys work, check if you have the right one.

On most laptops, to adjust the display luminosity you have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> + one of these keys:

[image]

---

For you it's the **Power Smart Utility** (from Acer website) :

http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Application/PowerSmart%20Manager/PowerSmart%20Manager_Acer_4.01.3013_Vistax64Vistax86_A.zip?acerid=633923232529485215&Step1=Notebook&Step2=Aspire&Step3=Aspire5738Z&OS=V10&LC=en&BC=Acer&SC=PA_6

Comment: I have a acer aspire 5738Z

Comment: This one is for your Acer model.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Power Options and you can change settings for a particular power plan.

[image]

There you can adjust the brightness for a given plan. I presume that your energy save button has the effect of changing the power plan.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting energy save button as hotkey for [DimScreen](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/#DimScreen).
If you want a different approach then you can try [DimSaver](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/#DimSaver) as default screensaver and make your energy save button to launch your screensaver if possible.